# How to add memo to transaction?

Tags: transactions, stellar-sdk, payments, memo

I want to create a transaction with a memo, but i keep getting error

```
this.memo.toXDRObject is not a function at TransactionBuilder.build
```

code:

```
    let fee = await get_mining_fee();

    const txOpts = {
        fee:fee,
        //memo : t.memo,
        networkPassphrase : get_stellar_network_from_env()
    }
    

    const payment = {
        destination : address,
        asset : Stellar.Asset.native(),
        amount : amount+""
    }
    console.log(payment)
    const stellar_transaction = new Stellar.TransactionBuilder(our_account , txOpts)
        .addMemo(t.memo)
        .addOperation(Stellar.Operation.payment(payment))
        .setTimeout(Stellar.TimeoutInfinite)
        .build();

        stellar_transaction.sign(Stellar.Keypair.fromSecret(get_our_xlm_private_key()));

        await StellarServer.submitTransaction(stellar_transaction);
```

I tried putting memo in txOpts and i get the same error. How do i add memo to transaction ocrrectly? If i omit memo field then transaction succeeds. t.memo is a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
.addMemo(t.memo)
```

was changed to

```
.addMemo(StellarSdk.Memo.text(t.memo))
```